# How do I execute a dry run of a tar compression?

Tags: tar

I want to execute a dry run of a tar compression and print the entries to stdout without actually creating the tar.

So far I've tried:

```bsh
// just spins
$ tar t -O Downloads
```

```bsh
$ tar c -O Downloads
tar: Option -O is not permitted in mode -c
```

`tar --help` gives the following:

```bsh
⋊> ~ tar --help                                                                                                                                                                                 08:06:22
tar(bsdtar): manipulate archive files
First option must be a mode specifier:
  -c Create  -r Add/Replace  -t List  -u Update  -x Extract
Common Options:
  -b #  Use # 512-byte records per I/O block
  -f <filename>  Location of archive
  -v    Verbose
  -w    Interactive
Create: tar -c [options] [<file> | <dir> | @<archive> | -C <dir> ]
  <file>, <dir>  add these items to archive
  -z, -j, -J, --lzma  Compress archive with gzip/bzip2/xz/lzma
  --format {ustar|pax|cpio|shar}  Select archive format
  --exclude <pattern>  Skip files that match pattern
  -C <dir>  Change to <dir> before processing remaining files
  @<archive>  Add entries from <archive> to output
List: tar -t [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, list only entries that match
Extract: tar -x [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, extract only entries that match
  -k    Keep (don't overwrite) existing files
  -m    Don't restore modification times
  -O    Write entries to stdout, don't restore to disk
  -p    Restore permissions (including ACLs, owner, file flags)
bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To do a dry-run just listing files, use `-v` for verbose mode to list the files and [use /dev/null as output to avoid the time/space overhead of writing an acutal file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725144/can-i-get-a-faster-output-pipe-than-dev-null). Exclude `-v` if you just want to see tar errors.

```
tar -cvf /dev/null mydir
```

Comment: I like this better - single command with no pipe.  I have no idea if it is more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

`tar t` lists an existing archive. You haven't provided any as an argument (`-f`), so it's waiting for it on stdin. Humans are no good at typing tar archives on a keyboard, so it's not very useful.

`tar c` doesn't accept an `-O` option. It's an option to `x` as indicated in the help message.

You can combine those two to get expected result:

```
tar c Downloads | tar t
```

There's no `-f` argument to `tar c`, so it will write compressed output to stdout. We're then piping it to `tar t`'s stdin, using the mode in which it was "stuck" previously.